# Mysql query returning result even table is empty

Tags: mysql, select

i am using this query to get result sorted by most content_id, problem is even if request table is empty it is still returning me 1 element from content table:

```
select `c`.`id`, `c`.`title`, `c`.`slug`, `c`.`year`, `c`.`category`, `r`.*
, count(*) from requests as r
RIGHT JOIN `content` as c ON `r`.`content_id` = `c`.`id`
group by content_id order by count(*) desc
LIMIT 10
```

And if there are some records like 5 records in request table, it is returning me 6 records. First record is not in requests table.
Can someone help me please? Thanks

Comment: Trying using `INNER JOIN` instead of `RIGHT JOIN`

Comment: ah right, it was that simple, Please post as answer so i can accept this question.... Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying using `INNER JOIN` instead of `RIGHT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

When you use an aggregate function like `COUNT()` you're always going to get a row returned so the database can report the result of that function, even if it is zero.

Comment: Thank you , I updated my question. And if there are some records like 5 records in request table, its returning me 6 records.